# Input text not being displayed on Html Page

Tags: javascript, html

I and trying to make a basic web page as a project and can not get my text to display for a label tag being injected using javaScript.
If anyone has any ideas or could point me in the right direction that would be great.
Here is a snippet of the code I am having trouble with.

```
let todo = [
  {
    text: "Item 1",
    completed: true,
  },
  {
    text: "Item 2",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    text: "Item 3",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    text: "Item 4",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    text: "Item 5",
    completed: true,
  },
];
todo.forEach(function (todos, index) {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = `newTodo${index}`;
  checkBox.value = `todoItem${index}`;
  const checkBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
  checkBoxLabel.htmlFor = `todoItem${index}`;
  checkBoxLabel.innerText = todos.text; //"This is the text that is not being rendered to the browser"
 
  document
    .querySelector("#todoItem")
    .appendChild(div)
    .appendChild(checkBox)
    .appendChild(checkBoxLabel);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually working. But its generating the labels inside the checkbox input. Thats why you are not able to see it.

##### The issue is with the below section

```
document
    .querySelector("#todoItem")
    .appendChild(div)
    .appendChild(checkBox)
    .appendChild(checkBoxLabel)
```

##### What this does?

This will first select an element from the DOM having id `todoItem`. **Inside** that your div will be appended. Inside that div, the `checkBox` which is the input, will get appended. Inside that input `checkBoxLabel` which is the label will be appended.

So your heirarchy will be like, div inside the container `#todoItem`, `checkBox` inside that div, `checkBoxLabel` inside `checkBox`.

You were appending `checkBoxLabel` inside the checkbox. It should be in the same level of checkbox OR the input can be placed inside the label. A label inside a checkbox will not be visible. You can either place the `checkbox` inside the `label` OR both `checkbox` and `label` in same hierarchy inside `div`.

##### Placing checkbox inside label

```
document
  .querySelector("#todoItem")
  .appendChild(div)
  .appendChild(checkBoxLabel)
  .appendChild(checkBox);
```

This will make the checkbox to be placed after the label. like the one below

[image]

##### Placing checkbox and label inside the div with same hierarchy.

```
div
  .appendChild(checkBox);
div
  .appendChild(checkBoxLabel);

document
  .querySelector("#todoItem")
  .appendChild(div);
```

This will display the checkbox first, then the label like below

[image]

**Please find the working fiddle** with the second example.

```js
const todo = [
  { text: "Item 1", completed: true, },
  { text: "Item 2", completed: false, },
  { text: "Item 3", completed: false, },
  { text: "Item 4", completed: false, },
  { text: "Item 5", completed: true, },
];
todo.forEach(function (todos, index) {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  const checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = `newTodo${index}`;
  checkBox.value = `todoItem${index}`;

  // added checking condition
  checkBox.checked = todos.completed;

  const checkBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
  checkBoxLabel.htmlFor = `todoItem${index}`;
  checkBoxLabel.innerText = todos.text;

  // Place checkbox first then the label, Both on the div
  div
    .appendChild(checkBox);
  div
    .appendChild(checkBoxLabel);

  document
    .querySelector("#todoItem")
    .appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="todoItem"></div>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that out the way you did. I thought it had something to do with the order i was appending.